# Laravel / Eloquent hasMany relationship with no foreign key

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, has-many, multiple-databases

I have a model (Client) with a hasMany relationship to another  (Client_option).

The two tables are in different databases (so there is a list of clients, and then each client has their own database with an options table within).

In my Client class I want my options() method to return the entire contents of the options table (it knows which client db to look for). As it is I get an error because the column client_id does not exist in the options table. I can of course create that column and populate every row with the client's id, but I'd only be doing it to keep Eloquent happy so would rather avoid that little messiness.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Geoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will allow you to work with it as a relation, call it as dynamic property `$user->options`, bulk save with `push` method and so on:

```php
public function options()
{
  // it will use the same connection as user model
  $options = ClientOption::on($this->getConnectionName())->get();

  // if options model has its own, then simply
  // $options = ClientOption::get();

  $this->setRelation('options', $options);

  return $options;
}

public function getOptionsAttribute()
{
  return (array_key_exists('options', $this->relations))

    // get options from the relation, if already loaded
    ? $this->getRelation('options')

    // otherwise call the method and load the options
    : $this->options();
}
```

Comment: This works really well and as described, but I do get an error when I try to eager load the options relationship like so: Client::with('options')->find($client_id); I get the error "Call to undefined method App\Models\Base\Custom_collection::addEagerConstraints()" (Custom_collection extends Collection). I tried having the options() method return $this->getRelation('options') instead of $options but no joy. Any thoughts? Am happy with your answer and will mark as correct either way. Thanks!

Comment: This is a pseudo-relation. That said, you can't rely on all relation features of Eloquent, eager loading being one of them.